# Save list of dictionaries to .tsv file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following piece of code to output to csv.

```
import csv
keys = ['Name','Hour','Time']
dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
csvfilename = os.path.join(dirname, 'CSVFile.csv')
with open(csvfilename, 'wb') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(final)
```

where `final` is a list of dictionaries of the form

```
final = [{'Name':'A','Hour':0,'Time':120},{'Name':'A','Hour':1,'Time':219},...,{'Name':'B','Hour':0,'Time':10},...]
```

How can I output final to .tsv format?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify that in your `DictWriter` with the `delimiter` option:

```
dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys, delimiter='\t')
```

Or using the `dialect`:

```
dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys, dialect='excel-tab')
```

Comment: Thank you. Also, changed `csvfilename = os.path.join(dirname, 'TSVFile.tsv')`